# Are crazy icons here to stay?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, design, hot-network-questions

Am I the only on ELU whose icons are all shifted, some to the point that it is difficult to tell which is which?

[The issue has been raised on META](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/390757) where they mention a temporary problem when new SE sites are launched, but the problem has been going on for quite a few days now.

Is this issue being fixed?  First time I’ve seen this in years actually.

Edit:

As of today all icons are back to normal! Thanks

Comment: Go home, icons, you're drunk! (Mood.) I'm only seeing it on Stack Overflow at least

Comment: @Laurel - not sure what you mean. All icons on the hot list, for instance,  are still shifted, or skewed. But it is just me, probably. Amen

Comment: I'm referencing a [high quality meme](https://amp.knowyourmeme.com/memes/go-home-you-are-drunk). Since the main meta post has [tag:status-review], there's nothing much to do here. (You can flag/ping us when the issue is resolved.)

Comment: It was fixed for me on Stack Overflow (the only site where I saw an issue). Was the problem resolved for those who saw it here?

Answer (score 3):

The [MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/390757/sites-icons-appear-shifted-wrong-sites-icons-are-appearing) is [now marked as being](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/390757/3) [status-completed](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed), as of four hours ago, and the icons look normal again. (The bug was a byproduct of a new site, PLDI, [leaving private Beta](https://langdev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379/leaving-private-beta-and-initial-pro-tempore-moderator-election).)

So I think this has been fixed!

Comment: As of now, icons are still shifted as they were before as far as I am concerned. It may probably be also a problem of device (I am using an IPad). Anyway thanks for your  help.

Comment: @user66974 Silly question, I know, it's probably the first thing you tried, but have you tried rebooting? If the icons still do not match why not post a screenshot with the specs (details) of your iPad. Maybe other users have the same bug but haven't noticed yet?

Comment: Did you actually see the bug @Heartspring? It's still broken for me (on Stack Overflow).

Comment: @Mari-LouA It's not that type of bug; the issue is on the server. They need to "reboot" their cache. (PS it's hard to not notice [the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8W5l.png) if you have it).

Comment: Why is the bug only affecting a few sites? In user 66974's case, it seems multiple sites are affected. It also seems that they see the icons mismatch on EL&U too.

Comment: @Laurel - thanks for the link, those are exactly the distorted icons I’m still seeing at the moment on ELU.

Comment: At the moment, I'm still seeing the strangely shifted icons.

Comment: Seems to be fixed now, at least for me. (even though only two days ago still broken). Maybe it took a long while for the fix to propagate?